# Using linux 'screen' command from python

Tags: python, linux, process, gnu-screen

I am running several processes over a cluster.
I start every process separately using screen command.
It allows me to disconnect from the cluster and when connected view my processes.
Starting all the screens one by one is a painful job.
I am wondering if we could do it with a python script. 
The scrip opens the new shell creates the screen runs the process and disconnects.
Writes info about all the started processes in a text file like process id starting commands etc.

Secondly, I would like to stop the processes, I would like to put the pid to file and just run a command which will kill all the mentioned processes.

for example

the smaple inut file looks like

```
   process_name      command
      123            python batch_training.py
```

I would like to start the screen with the name given in process_name and the commend will be executed in the corresponding frame.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run your command without opening screen session, you should also use -dmS options with screen. So if you want to do that with python, Your code could look like this:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["screen", "-dmS", "screen_name_1", "top"])
subprocess.call(["screen", "-dmS", "screen_name_2", "top"])
subprocess.call(["screen", "-r"])
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you give the screen object a command in python?

Like:

```
from os import system

command = 'screen ' + '/dev/ttyUSB0 38400'
result = system(command)

result('ATZ')???
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "os.system()" with standart Linux commands.
e.g.:

```
os.system("screen nano")
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, in python, you can run system commands by running

`from os import system`

and then

`system('whatever_shell_command')`

So in your case you would type:

```
from os import system
system('screen')
```

Unfortunately (this is only sort of related) you can't run more then one command together, so

`system('shell_command ', argument)`

will not work.

so if you want to do that, you will need to concatenate the two strings:

```
full_command = 'shell_command ' + argument 
system(full_command)`
```